# Can't figure out how to get the description field for the field I want in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm working in Microsoft SQL Server 2008 and the purpose of the query is to look up all the materials used to make a certain part. In this case a `#DT05-BASE`.

The query returns the part description of the part '#DT05-BASE' but I want the part description of the part material, STE0560. Both are parts in the `Part` table with descriptions.

This is my query:

```
SELECT 
    PartMtl.PartNum, PartMtl.MtlPartNum, Part.PartDescription, 
    PartMtl.QtyPer 
FROM 
    PartMtl
JOIN 
    Part ON PartMtl.PartNum = Part.PartNum
WHERE 
    PartMtl.PartNum LIKE '#DT05-BASE' 
    AND Part.InActive = 0
```

This is my result and for every material that is listed the description will be the same, DINNING TABLE BASE

```
|#DT05-BASE |STE0560    |DINING TABLE BASE   |10.0
```

This what I want:

```
|#DT05-BASE |STE0560    |1"x 1" Flat Bar   |10.0
```

Which is the description of STE0560 and I would want the description of every other material that is listed that is used to make the #DT05-BASE.

Is this possible?

Comment: Please review tips on asking SQL questions.  There is not really enough information here for anyone to help you without making lots of assumptions... http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056

Comment: Please provide more information lie what is 1"x1" and where it is stored?

Comment: @atp9 You can see where the `1"x1"` comes from in the query.

Comment: @ammills01 What specifically do you think is missing?

Comment: @Chris, I think you are referring to wrong column in your query. It would be great if you can provide sample data with Column names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your query it looks like your `JOIN` is wrong.

```
JOIN 
    Part ON PartMtl.PartNum = Part.PartNum
```

It appears you want the part description for `PartMtl.MtlPartNum` but you are joining it to the `PartMtl.PartNum`.  Try this...

```
JOIN 
    Part ON PartMtl.MtlPartNum = Part.PartNum
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Cody360c that fixed my issue.  This was my first post and I will make sure to include column headings with my sample data in the future.

Comment: @Chris No problem:). If it truly did help you then please make sure to select it as the answer! Thanks.